# Consumir WebAPI pelo AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um método POST na WebAPI, e esta definido o RoutePrefix da Api, a Route do método POST e o Cors esta habilitado.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/crm")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class EmpresaParticipanteController : ApiController
{
    private SigCodeFirst db = new SigCodeFirst();

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("registros")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostRegistro(EmpresaParticipante empresaParticipante)
    {
        if (empresaParticipante == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        try
        {
            db.EmpresaParticipante.Add(empresaParticipante);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var resultado = empresaParticipante;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, resultado);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Falha ao incluir registro.");
        }
    }
}
```

No AngularJs, o script esta da seguinte maneira:

```
var crmApp = angular.module("Crm", []);
crmApp.controller("CrmCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

   $scope.adicionarRegistro = function (empresaParticipante) {
       $http.post("http://grupo.ddns.net/GRUPO/api/v1/crm/registros", empresaParticipante).success(function (data) {
           delete $scope.empresaParticipante;
           $scope.novoCrmForm.$setPristine();
           console.log(empresaParticipante);
           carregarRegistros();
       });
   };
});
```

na URI esta assim: http://grupo.ddns.net/GRUPO/api/v1/crm/registros

Dominio: `http://grupo.ddns.net`

Diretório dentro do servidor (onde código esta publicado): `GRUPO/`

RoutePrefix (da API): `api/v1/crm/`

Route (método POST): `registros`

**O Problema é o seguinte:**

quando coloco esta aplicação na net, esta apresentando um erro de caminho não encontrado (404) nesta URI acima.

Diante essa estrutura do servidor com diretório, e as Routes da API, como devo montar a URI para funcionar o cadastro na net?
Ou, devo fazer algo diferente para funcionar melhor?

Lembrando que o Servidor fica na empresa e como visto no domínio acima, não tem IP fixo.

Answer (score 1):

Bruno, bom dia. Então, no teste de portas que eu utilizo com frequência mostra que não tem porta 80 (http) aberta no seu IP.

Utilize este site para checar, você precisa passar por este procedimento senão não vai funcionar. Se você tem um IP público que seja dinâmico, muito provavelmente você vai precisar só abrir a porta no(s) roteador(es) para o IP da sua máquina.

Site para teste de portas: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
Bota teu IP público e a porta 80. Enquanto não der positivo ninguém vai acessar.

Answer (score 0):

Em teoria, sem ter acesso às demais configurações do Web Api, está tudo certo.

Você tem acesso aos los do servidor Web onde a aplicação foi publicada para conferir se a requisição realmente chegou até ele (pode haver algum problema com proxy, dns, etc, de modo que a requisição não esteja realmente chegando na sua aplicação)?

Se você confirmou no log do servidor que a requisição registrou o erro 404, você pode tentar ativar o [Failed Request Tracing do IIS](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) para descobrir o motivo do erro no pipeline do IIS.